# Unbalanced multiclass classification pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation, imbalanced-data

I have a matrix X (features, dim 320x7) and an array y (targets, dim 320x1) in a 3-class classification problem. I've implemented GridsearchCV for 5 different models to check which one is the best and tune its hyperparameters. To be as rigorous as possible, I created a pipeline to perform data preprocessing on each fold. Pipeline includes scaling, resampling and the classifier.

Since the target vector is unbalanced (see pic), I used SMOTE to balance the three classes. Now, the issue is, despite I think the order of the whole process is correct, I am getting training accuracies very high (0.9 - 0.99) but poor test accuracies (0.5 - 0.55), and I cannot figure if this is due to overfitting for bad hyperparameter space search or is due to my data quality.

I would appreciate if someone could shine a light on it. Thanks.

[image: Class distribution]

And here is the code

```
# Import modules

import pickle
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.model_selection import  GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Load features and target
with open('data.pkl','rb') as f: 
    dataset = pickle.load(f) 
X = dataset['X']
y = dataset['y']

#%% Grid-search cross validation for different models

# Model search space
models = {
            'LogisticRegression'     : LogisticRegression(),
            'SVM'                    : SVC(),
            'RandomForestClassifier' : RandomForestClassifier(),
            'BaggingClassifier'      : BaggingClassifier(),
            'KNN'                    : KNeighborsClassifier()}

# Hyperparameter search space
hyper = {
            'LogisticRegression':{
                                        'clf__penalty'     : ['l2'],
                                        'clf__C'           : np.logspace(-4, 4, 10),
                                        'clf__solver'      : ['lbfgs', 'newton-cg', 'saga'],
                                        'clf__max_iter'    : [1000, 1500, 2000],
                                        'clf__random_state': [0]},
            
            'SVM':{
                                        'clf__C'           : [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000],
                                        'clf__gamma'       : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001],
                                        'clf__kernel'      : ['rbf', 'linear'],
                                        'clf__random_state': [0]},
            
            'RandomForestClassifier':{
                                        'clf__max_depth': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                                        'clf__max_features': [2, 3, 4, 'auto', 'sqrt'],
                                        'clf__n_estimators': [10, 100, 500, 1000],
                                        'clf__random_state': [0]},
           
            'KNN':{
                                        'clf__n_neighbors': [3, 4, 8, 16]},
            
            'BaggingClassifier':{
                                        'clf__base_estimator': [DecisionTreeClassifier()],
                                        'clf__max_samples'   : [0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5],
                                        'clf__n_estimators'  : [10, 50, 100, 500],
                                        'clf__max_features'  : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]}
        }

# Create variable to store CV results
grid_cv_results = dict()

# Scaler 
escaler = MinMaxScaler()

# Resampling
resampler = SMOTE(sampling_strategy = 'all', random_state = 0)

# Perform cross-validation for each model
for model_name in models.keys():
    
    # Get model and hyperparameters
    clf    = models[model_name]
    params = hyper[model_name]
    
    # Pipeline (standarization + classifier)
    pipe = Pipeline([('scale', escaler), 
                     ('sampling', resampler), 
                     ('clf', clf)])
    
    # Gridsearch cross-validation
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = params, cv = 5, return_train_score = True)
    grid.fit(X, y)
    
    # Gridsearch cross-validation results
    best_param                  = grid.best_params_
    best_param_test_score_mean  = grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][grid.best_index_]
    best_param_test_score_std   = grid.cv_results_['std_test_score'][grid.best_index_]
    best_param_train_score_mean = grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score'][grid.best_index_]
    best_param_train_score_std  = grid.cv_results_['std_train_score'][grid.best_index_]
    
    # Store gridsearch cross-validation results
    grid_cv_results[model_name] = {
                                      'best_param'                  : best_param,
                                      'best_param_test_score_mean'  : best_param_test_score_mean,
                                      'best_param_test_score_std'   : best_param_test_score_std,
                                      'best_param_train_score_mean' : best_param_train_score_mean,
                                      'best_param_train_score_std'  : best_param_train_score_std,
```

Comment: you could stratify your sample, read more here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators-with-stratification-based-on-class-labels

Comment: Hey Miguel, as long as I know from the docs, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html, the "cv" parameter of GridSearchCV already performs stratified CV when an integer is passed.

Comment: @Eduardo don't you think resampler  should not be part of model pipeline since it will do oversampling for train and test data seperately during grid.fit and also when you you use grid.predict to predict any new test data? I believe you should do oversampling on complete data at once outside model pipeline.